# TinyMCE editor loaded through AJAX not working

Tags: javascript, ajax, editor

I've built a form that calls for an editor to be loaded through AJAX, but when I insert the fetched contents I get only a `<textarea>`. If I hit the toggle editor button, then the editor gets built, but it uses the default configuration for TinyMCE instead of how Joomla tries to configure it.

My Javascript:

```
$.ajax({
    method:'GET',
    url:'fetchEditor.php'
}).done(function(response) {
    $('#main').append(response);
});
```

fetchEditor.php:

```
<?php
$editor = JFactory::getEditor('tinymce');
echo $editor->display('text', '', 'auto', 'auto', 55, 15, false);
?>
```

I tried throwing in some Javascript to re-init TinyMCE for this editor, but it also just uses the default configuration instead of what Joomla uses.

Answer (score 2):

After spending more time searching for possibilities, I found that Joomla includes the file `/media/editors/tinymce/js/tinymce.min.js`, and upon opening the uncompressed version of the file and reading through it, I saw that it has the function `Joomla.JoomlaTinyMCE.setupEditors();` which handles the initialization of all instances of TinyMCE on the page.

So, after the AJAX loads the new editor, recalling `Joomla.JoomlaTinyMCE.setupEditors();` will handle everything.

Comment: Well, after going through some of my use cases, I noticed that some config options weren't being set properly unless another editor was already on the page. Trying to resolve now.